# Bootstrap datetimepicker doesn't retrieve in correct format

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using `BootstrapDateTimePicker` and it does select the date/time in the desired format, however when I retrieve the data it doesn't show the time it only shows the date.

```
    $('#publishDate_Text').datetimepicker({
        format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A",
        pick12HourFormat: true
    });
```

**Html**:

```
<div id="publishDate_Text" class="input-group date">
      <input class="form-control valid" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm A" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field PublicationForProposal must be a date." id="publishDate" name="publishDate" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="15/10/2014">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
      </span>
</div>
```

When I select from the datetimepicker it displays the date/time as '**DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A**' but when it retrieves the date (from database), it displays only the date in this format '**DD/MM/YYYY**' without the time.

Why is that happening?

Comment: What does the value being pulled from the database look like? odds are you are only storing the date in the database and not the datetime

Comment: It's datetime, if I remove the datetimepicker, I get a full datetime as it has been saved